# Why is my WordPress website not getting indexed on Google Search Console despite using Yoast SEO and manually creating a sitemap and robots.txt?

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress, sitemap, robots.txt, yoast

I have added my website in my Google Search Console but it's not getting indexed. It's a WordPress website and I'm using Yoast SEO but since it didn't work out. I had to create Sitemap manually and then upload it to the root of the website as this was suggested by hosting.

Basically, I'm getting error "Couldn't Fetch" for the uploaded sitemap.xml (screenshot attached) and I think it's because High Fail Rate of robots.txt (screenshot attached).

I never had to touch robots or sitemap while working on Wordpress since Yoast SEO or any SEO related plugins usually takes care of that but this is the first time I'm facing this issue that's why I had to generate Sitemap.xml and Robots.txt (actually Bluehost created those files).

[image]

[image]

Comment: No one to answer here?

Comment: Something from your server is blocking Google from reading your site. In Google Search Console, go to URL Inspection and enter the url of a page, or the sitemap. It may give you further indications of the error. Alternatively, try to look into your server's log